# Creating Blackjack simulation in Ruby, altering variables between different instances

Tags: ruby, blackjack

This is for a job interview. What I want to do is that once a card is dealt (removed from the Dealer's Deck instance), that card becomes available to the Player's Hand Instance.

```
    class Card
      attr_accessor :suite, :name, :value #specifiy that class attributes are both, readable and writable
      #constructor
      def initialize(suite, name, value) 
        @suite, @name, @value = suite, name, value #this looks odd
      end
    end

    class Deck
      attr_accessor :playable_cards
      SUITES = [:hearts, :diamonds, :spades, :clubs] #constant 
      NAME_VALUES = { 
        :two   => 2,
        :three => 3,
        :four  => 4,
        :five  => 5,
        :six   => 6,
        :seven => 7,
        :eight => 8,
        :nine  => 9,
        :ten   => 10,
        :jack  => 10,
        :queen => 10,
        :king  => 10,
        :ace   => [11, 1]}

      def initialize #initialzing shuffles the deck
        shuffle 
      end

      def deal_card #removes card from deck
        random = rand(@playable_cards.size) #returns an random int greater >= 0 & < max
        @playable_cards.delete_at(random)
      end

      def shuffle
        @playable_cards = [] #array of 52 cards
        SUITES.each do |suite| #iterate over suites
          NAME_VALUES.each do |name, value| #iterate, over card for that suite
            @playable_cards << Card.new(suite, name, value) #add to end of array, new Card
          end
        end
      end
    end

    class Hand
      attr_accessor :cards

      def initialize
        @cards = []
      end
    end

    class Player
      def initialize
        @player_hand = Hand.new
      end

    end

    class Dealer 
      def initialize
        @dealer_hand = Hand.new
        @dealer_deck = Deck.new
      end

      def deal 
        card = @dealer_deck.deal_card
      end
    end


require 'test/unit'

class CardTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @card = Card.new(:hearts, :ten, 10)
  end

  def test_card_suite_is_correct
    assert_equal @card.suite, :hearts
  end

  def test_card_name_is_correct
    assert_equal @card.name, :ten
  end
  def test_card_value_is_correct
    assert_equal @card.value, 10
  end
end

class DeckTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @deck = Deck.new
  end

  def test_new_deck_has_52_playable_cards
    assert_equal @deck.playable_cards.size, 52
  end

  def test_dealt_card_should_not_be_included_in_playable_cards
    card = @deck.deal_card
    assert(!@deck.playable_cards.include?(card)) #upon dealing card, card should be removed from deck
  end

  def test_shuffled_deck_has_52_playable_cards
    @deck.shuffle
    assert_equal @deck.playable_cards.size, 52
  end
end
```

All I have done is added the `Player` and `Dealer` class. My thinking is that a Player has a hand so upon initialization an instance of a Hand is stored in `@player_hand` and the same goes for the Dealer. The Dealer also has its own deck instance, obviously. Now once I call `Dealer.new.deal` a card is removed from the deck, how do I add that newly removed card to the `Player @player_hand`?

I thought about using global variables, but that's bad practice. I'm also not quite sure if this is even the right approach.

Comment: Where are your automated tests for this?

Comment: Tests have been added. I've also been asked to create my own tests as needed. All tests so far are passing.

Comment: awesome tests! you're hired. Oh, except `assert_equal @deck.playable_cards.size, 52` should be `assert_equal 52, @deck.playable_cards.size`, and `assert(!(...))` should be `refute`, and you should drop excess parentheses `()` on assertions.

Comment: Why do Players and Dealers need their own class?  Wouldn't they be an instance of Hand? Where they then receive a card from the Deck you initialise.  I assume you didn't write the shuffle method as it actually does no shuffling at all, that is actually done by the random select (deal_card). After your basic tests, you would need to look at what rules you want to use, ie when does a dealer have to draw are a card and when do they have to sit ... and of course the 21 limit

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need some place for an a player and a dealer to exist in. From that context you will have the control to pass around cards between the dealer and the player. Also there could be several players or something.

So I would create a Game class, where you initialize Players and dealer and you can create methods to hand around cards.

```
class Game
  def initialize
    @dealer = Dealer.new
    @player = Player.new
  end

  def deal_out_to_player
    2.times do
      @player.player_hand.cards << Dealer.deal
    end 
  end
end
```